# Ubuntu does not recognize USB external monitor

Tags: ubuntu

I have my laptop Lenovo Z360 with Nvidia GeForce 310M (driver 340.96) and just updated from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04
I'm trying to connect the USB monitor Samsung SyncMaster LD190
Well, when connecting the Monitor before Boot the system recognizes the USB monitor and I can use it but it automatically disables the laptop display. After disconnecting the USB monitor the controls comes back to the laptop display but requires new login typing the password.
Please let me know for any help.
Thanks
Edson